# Laid down the gauntlet meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a book I'm reading there is a sentence like this

> Einstein laid down the gauntlet by considering as valid only two ways of understanding time.

I guess that laid down the gauntlet means challenge someone/start a debate, but I'm not sure about that.

Please explain for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The previous version, 'Definition of “throw the gauntlet down” ', was closed as genref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual term is [*throw down the gauntlet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauntlet_(glove)#.22Throw_down_the_gauntlet.22), referring to the practice of challenging someone to a duel by throwing your gauntlet (glove) down in front of the person you're challenging.

*Laid down the gauntlet* is not the usual idiom, but apparently is used, with the same meaning.

Comment: Perhaps "lay down" is used to imply it's a more gentle or polite action than throwing it down.